# Define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of real number by $a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac {a_n^2 +1 } {2} , \text{for}\ n \geq 1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of real number by $$a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac {a_n^2 +1 } {2} , \text{for}\  n \geq 1 $$ Then prove that $$\displaystyle {\sum_{j=1}^N \frac {1}{a_j +1} < 1 }$$for every natural number N.

---

I don't know how to solve this problem, please give me some ideas to start in a right way to reach the solution.

**This question is from R.M.O 2018 Tamilnadu region.**

Comment: Can you prove the sum at a point is than $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{2^j}$ at a point? Can you prove after that point $a_{n}>2^n$?

Comment: When did the competition end? Or is it an ongoing/active competition?

Comment: @rtybase This link: https://secure.hbcse.tifr.res.in/rmo/index.php indicates that the exam for the R.M.O 2018 Tamilnadu region took place almost three days ago

Comment: @quantus14 that's suspiciously close, we [should probably not](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) post any answers for now

Comment: I only just found out that the question above is a possible duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977671/sequence-inequality-question-from-rmo-2018?rq=1

Comment: @quantus14 oh, [Sylvester sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_sequence), no wonder this looks so familiar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I have seen this many years ago (back in the days in the discussion group sci.math). In any event, notice
$$\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{2}{x^2-1} = \frac{1}{\frac{x^2+1}{2}-1}$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{a_j-1} - \frac{1}{a_j+1} = \frac{1}{a_{j+1}+1}$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{a_j+1}
&= \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{a_j-1} - \frac{1}{a_{j+1}-1}\right)
= \frac{1}{a_1-1} - \frac{1}{a_{N+1}-1}\\
&< \frac{1}{a_1-1} = \frac{1}{2-1} = 1\end{align}$$
because $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{a_{N+1}-1}$ is clearly positive.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n=\displaystyle {\sum_{j=1}^n \frac {1}{a_j +1}}$

I'm going to show by induction that $\displaystyle {1-S_n=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1} \Rightarrow 1-S_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_{n+2}-1}}$

If this is proven to be true then $\displaystyle {S_n=1-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}<1}$

**Base case**: $\displaystyle {S_1=\frac{1}{3},a_2=\frac{5}{2}}$

$\displaystyle {1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{\frac{5}{2}-1}\Rightarrow\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}}\Rightarrow\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3}}$

**Inductive Step**:

$\displaystyle {1-S_n=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}}$

$\displaystyle {1-S_n-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}+1}=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}+1}}$

$\displaystyle {1-(S_n+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}+1})=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}+1}}$

$\displaystyle {1-(S_{n+1})=\frac{a_{n+1}+1}{(a_{n+1}-1)(a_{n+1}+1)}-\frac{a_{n+1}-1}{(a_{n+1}-1)(a_{n+1}+1)}}$

$\displaystyle {1-S_{n+1}=\frac{2}{(a_{n+1}-1)(a_{n+1}+1)}}$

$\displaystyle {1-S_{n+1}=\frac{2}{a_{n+1}^2-1}}$

By definition $\displaystyle {a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}^2+1}{2}\Rightarrow a_{n+2}-1=\frac{a_{n+1}^2-1}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{a_{n+2}-1}=\frac{2}{a_{n+1}^2-1}}$

$\displaystyle {1-S_{n+1}=\frac{2}{a_{n+1}^2-1}=\frac{1}{a_{n+2}-1}}$

Thus completing the proof.

Comment: It's funny how Olympiad problems always have a simple solution (or at least, one that looks simple when you say it). +1